# What is the ID of the 'MessageReceived' sound on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to use the 'ReceivedMessage' sound on macOS using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` but I can't seem to find the ID anywhere.
**What I've tried:**

1. I've looked under `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds` and couldn't find it either - although `MessageSent` is there.
2. I've tried `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003)` as well following this [link](https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/AudioServices) but that just results in silence. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
3. I've tried looking in `Messages > Show Package Contents` which only led to more disappointment.
4. I found the file [here](https://github.com/extratone/macOSsystemsounds) but I was a hoping to just link to it directly rather than including the .caf file in my app bundle.